# How do I use asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol?

Tags: async-await, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I am trying to talk to an ElectrumX server using JSON-RPC over TLS, but through Tor (SOCKS proxy on localhost).

When running the following code, `drain()` in  `asyncio.streams` is calling `_drain_helper` in SSLProtocol, which I don't know how to implement.

If I just make it a no-op, it seems to not work.

I know that the JSON-RPC server is working because I have tested with

```
echo -ne '{"id":0,"args":["3.0.2","1.1"],"method":"server.version"}\n' | socat stdio openssl-connect:songbird.bauerj.eu:50002,verify=0
```

My attempt at using TLS through SOCKS in Python with asyncio:

```
from asyncio.sslproto import SSLProtocol
import aiosocks
import asyncio

loop = None

class MySSLProtocol(SSLProtocol):
    def __init__(otherself):
        super().__init__(loop, None,      False  , None)
        #                      app_proto  context  waiter

async def l(fut):
    try:
        socks4addr = aiosocks.Socks4Addr("127.0.0.1", 9050)
        transport, protocol = await aiosocks.create_connection(MySSLProtocol, proxy=socks4addr, proxy_auth=None, dst=("songbird.bauerj.eu", 50002))
        reader = asyncio.StreamReader()
        reader.set_transport(transport)
        writer = asyncio.StreamWriter(transport, protocol, reader, loop)
        writer.write(b'{"id":0,"method":"server.version","args":["3.0.2", "1.1"]}\n')
        await writer.drain()
        print(await reader.readuntil(b"\n"))
        fut.set_result("finished")
    except BaseException as e:
        fut.set_exception(e)


def f():
    global loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fut = asyncio.Future()
    asyncio.ensure_future(l(fut))
    loop.run_until_complete(fut)
    print(fut.result())
    loop.close()

f()
```

I am using `aiosocks` from master. Commit `932374c`

Answer (score 0):

`asyncio.sslproto` and `SSLProtocol` are part of asyncio private API.

You should never use the class directly or derive from it.

For working with SSL please pass normal protocol (derived from `asyncio.Protocol`) and `ssl.SSLContext` as `ssl` param into `loop.create_connection()` / `loop.create_server()`.

Comment: As stated, I want to use SSL tunnelled in SOCKS. Passing SSL to create_connection is going to get me an SSL-encrypted SOCKS connection, I want it the other way around. If you don't think SSLProtocol is the appropriate solution, show me how to do SSL in SOCKS without it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it like so:

```py
class HTTP(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, config: Config):
        self.config = config

    def data_received(self, data) -> None:
        print(data)


class HTTPS:
    def __new__(cls, config: Config):
        ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
        ssl_context.load_cert_chain(config.rsa_cert, config.rsa_key)

        return asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol(
            loop=asyncio.get_running_loop(),
            app_protocol=HTTP(config),
            sslcontext=ssl_context,
            waiter=None,
            server_side=True,
        )
```

See [`mitm`](https://github.com/synchronizing/mitm/) for working example. Not the way I would've chosen to use it, but the only way I could figure out. From my knowledge there is no way to upgrade an `asyncio.Protocol` to use SSL - you must create a new one.